# Django: prefetch related with sort by runs multiple queries

Tags: python, django

I am using prefetch_related. When i want to sort the prefetch results, then it generates again sql,

```
class UserActivity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name= 'user_logging_details',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    ip_addess = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


users = User.objects.prefetch_related('user_logging_details').all()

for user in users:
    users_activity = user.user_logging_details.all()
    # this does not generate any sql

    ## VS ##

    users_activity = user.user_logging_details.all().sort_by('ip_addess')
    # this generates many sqls and defeats the purpose of prefetch related
```

How can sort the prefetch results.

What is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
prefetch = Prefetch('user_logging_details', queryset= UserActivity.objects.all().order_by('ip_address'))
users = User.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch).all()


for user in users:
    users_activity = user.user_logging_details.all()
    # it should return user activities ordered by ip address
```